# Intercepting @Transactional After Optimistic Lock for Asynchronous Calls in Restful App

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop, optimistic-locking

The question I have today is how to retry a method after the @Transactional annotation causes an Optimistic Lock Exception (OLE) and rolls back the transaction.

I have asynchronous calls to a Restful application that are attempting to update a database object based on some business logic. If I get an OLE, I'd like to retry the transaction after a delay of 0.2-0.5 seconds.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public Response myMethod(Long myParam) throws Exception {
    ~Call to update db using hibernate after business logic~;
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I've tried using AspectJ to intercept my method after it throws the OLE so that I can retry. However, the issue is the @Transactional annotation. My method is *not* throwing the error message since business logic is not failing. Instead, myMethod returns a 200 response, but the OLE exception is encountered and then thrown in the ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java class that is responsible for invoking myMethod.

My aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class myAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* com.package.blah.myClass.myMethod(..)) && args(.., myParam)", throwing = "ex")
    public Response catchAndRetry(JoinPoint jp, Throwable ex, Long myParam) throws Throwable {

        Response response = null; 

        response = invokeAndRetry(jp, myParam);

        return response;
    }
}
```

The invokeAndRetry() method has the logic to call wait on the thread and then retry up to a maximum of three tries.

I can successfully get into myAspect from an exception thrown by business logic; but the OLE thrown from the transaction does not get caught in myAspect.

Having said all of that, is there a way to wrap/encapsulate/intercept the @Transaction annotation in order to run my retry logic?

Side notes:

1) I've looked into creating my own @Retry annotation based on the example [here](http://vladmihalcea.com/optimistic-locking-retry-with-jpa/). I've used that dependency to try his @Retry annotation, but to no avail.

2) I'll be looking into Spring's @within to see if that could prove useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and looking at some more tutorials, I found a way to have my aspect take precedence over @Transactional. Just below the @Aspect tag, I added the annotation @Order(1).

This gives my aspect higher priority since @Transactional is defaulted to Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE. See [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) for some more details about @Order.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **you shouldn't try to reuse an `EntityManager` after an exception occurs**. According to the [Hibernate EntityManager User guide on Transactions and concurrency](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-exceptions), which most probably applies to all JPA providers:

> If the `EntityManager` throws an exception (including any `SQLException`), you should immediately rollback the database transaction, call `EntityManager.close()` (if `createEntityManager()` has been called) and discard the `EntityManager` instance. Certain methods of `EntityManager` will not leave the persistence context in a consistent state. No exception thrown by an entity manager can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the `EntityManager` will be closed by calling `close()` in a finally block. Note that a container managed entity manager will do that for you. You just have to let the `RuntimeException` propagate up to the container.

You might be able to do the retry the operation in a new transaction with a new instance of an `EntityManager` though, but that's a different use-case.